# Failed to set scrollview's position

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am new in iOS. I am building a basic project where I have two view controllers.
First one named as tabViewController and the second one as detailViewController.
in tabViewController I have a collectionView. When I am tapping on collection view cell it is pushing to detail view controller. In detail view controller there are three image views. One is just in front of the screen (x=0, y=0, width=320, height=420). The other two imageViews are in the positions at left and right side of the one which is in front of the screen. The two imageViews are in positions as x=-330,y=0,width=320,height=420 and x=330,y=0,width=320,height=420. Consider just about iPhone5.

Now, the problem that is happening is I cant make the scrollView's position to see the image that is in left side of the screen.

The code I have written is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myScrollView.delegate = self;
    _myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _selectedImageString = [_patternArray objectAtIndex:*(_selectedIndex)];
    _strImageNext = [_patternArray objectAtIndex:*(_selectedIndex)+1];
    _myScrollView.bounds = CGRectMake(_myImageView2.frame.origin.x, _myScrollView.frame.origin.y, _myScrollView.frame.size.width, _myScrollView.frame.size.height);

    if (*(_selectedIndex) == 0) {
        _strImagePrevious = nil;

    }
    else{

        _strImagePrevious = [_patternArray objectAtIndex:*(_selectedIndex)-1];

    }

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    _myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_selectedImageString];

    _myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(_myScrollView.frame.origin.x, _myScrollView.frame.origin.y, _myScrollView.frame.size.width, _myScrollView.frame.size.height);

    self.myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    _myImageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_strImageNext];

    if (*(_selectedIndex) == 0) {
        _myImageView2.image = nil;
    }
    else {
        _myImageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_strImagePrevious];

    }

    [_myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [_myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((_myImageView2.frame.size.width+_myImageView2.frame.size.width+_myImageView2.frame.size.width+_myImageView.frame.size.width+ 30.0), _myScrollView.frame.size.height)];


}
```

Comment: where are you setting the scroll's position? in your code it's only set the `contentSize` (you should set also the `contentOffset`)

Comment: I just want to know that how to use the contentOffset. Can you please help me with some code. @Javito_009

Comment: You can use `setContentOffset:animated:` method and pass `CGPointMake(x,y)` where 'x' and 'y' are the coordinates that correspond with the point that you want to see in the upper-left corner of the scrollView (doc: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset:animated:)).

Comment: And you also can use `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method and pass the frame of your imageView, and it scrolls automatically to display the imageView (doc: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/scrollRectToVisible:animated:)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to move left with contentOffset. Hope it will help you.

```
your_scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-100.0, 0.0);
```